# Error 1172 - Result consisted of more than one row - (simple update, no subquery) - MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql

Can somebody tell me what raises the : **Result consisted of more than one row** error ?

[image]

**UPDATED:**

2.The first update consisted of an outdated link

1.Here comes the table structure. I cant share the data because the it is consist of private emails (at the moment)

[check here the table structure](http://pastebin.com/9adtM90q)

Comment: can u post table data with dat particular id?

Comment: use distinct row `SELECT DISTINCTROW id, ..` or just `LIMIT 1` to ensure it will return only one row.

Comment: there is the result of the select too. It has only one row. And the update raises the error.

Comment: 1172 can only be produced if a stored procedure is involved someplace.  Does your database have an update trigger?

Comment: Bingo, It has update, and delete triggers ... MANY THANKS