# Result consisted of more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I run two simple queries but MySQL displays an error message and do not understand why.

**SELECT:**

```
SELECT proy_obs FROM proy WHERE proy_cod = 'C-12-001';
+-------------+
| proy_obs    |
+-------------+
|             |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
UPDATE proy SET proy_obs = 'Test' WHERE proy_cod = 'C-12-001';
ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row
```

**MySQL version:**

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.71, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Comment: Did you check links in the _"Related"_ column?

Comment: Yes but I see that more complex queries using joins, group by and sub ​​selects.

Comment: This post may be the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076360/error-1172-result-consisted-of-more-than-one-row-simple-update-no-subquery?rq=1
Thanks Alma Do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a trigger(s) defined on your table that is causing the problem.

To check it out run

```
select trigger_name 
  from information_schema.triggers 
 where trigger_schema = schema()
   and event_object_table = 'proy';
```

Comment: There is a trigger associated with the table "proy". Thanks @peterm.